# Image path problem in Laravel blade template

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

In my laravel project image is not showing. I am using voyager admin panel.
In database `image name` is

```
banners\March2019\xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg
```

In blade template using the below code to show image

`<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ url('/images/'.$data->banner_image) }}" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">`

Through inspect element I got image source as below

```
http://localhost:8000/images/bannersMarch2019xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg
```

Here no `slash` in this path `bannersMarch2019xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg`. But actual path is `banners/March2019/xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg`.

Because of this path problem image is not shown.
So my question is why there is **no slash** ? How can I solve that ?

Someone help me please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the output of `{{$data->banner_image}}`??

Comment: @InzamamIdrees...while I `dd` in my controller is shows `banners\March2019\xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg`

Comment: Are you sure the output of dd is banners\\March2019\\xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg. Maybe you have to recheck it in your Controller.

Comment: @benji127...while `dd` result is `banners\March2019\xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg`...
while `return` result is `banners\\March2019\\xqem6GRUtqSU6pyWZRDJ.jpg`

Comment: try to do this :  `src="{{ url('/images') }}/{!!$data->banner_image!!}"`

Comment: @InzamamIdrees...no change :(
It's blade template related probem. But can't fixed

Comment: Did you try to relocate the file and update the image path ? or try get another image instead from another source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in voyeger. Backslashes in media asset path when saving to db. You can solve it using,

```
$output = str_replace('\\', '/', $data->banner_image);
```

You can see this thread for more details : https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/2834#ref-commit-0d6bffb

Answer (score 0):

Double check your config/filesystems.php storage variable, you must upload / place your images in the

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

The "root" index here determines where your files would be located once you display it in the view, by default, it's being located at storage/app/public

Answer (score 0):

Please try this below. It should work.

```
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ url('/images/'. '/' . $data->banner_image) }}" data-color="lightblue" alt="First Image">
```